# How to get full black tick marks in Julia Plots Backend PGFPlotsX?

Tags: plot, julia, backend

I'm using the [Julia Plots Package](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl) with backend [PGFPlotsX](https://github.com/KristofferC/PGFPlotsX.jl#pgfplotsx) and I would like to make a plot where the tick marks appear in full black. This seems the default for other backends (I tested with `gr()` and `pyplot()`), but not for PGFPlotsX. Setting `foreground_color_axis=:black`, which should handle the [color of the axis ticks](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/generated/attributes_axis/), does not change the result.

MWE:

```
using Plots
pgfplotsx()
# this produces a plot with vague tick marks
p1 = plot(rand(20), foreground_color_axis=:black)

pyplot()
# this produces a plot with full black tick marks
p2 = plot(rand(20), foreground_color_axis=:black)
```

**Within the universal Syntax of Julia Plots package, is it possible to get full black tick marks with backend PGFPlotsX?**

I'm using `julia` version 1.3.1, `Plots` version 0.29.6 and `PGFPlotsX` version 1.2.4.

By zoom-inspection of an output .pdf I just found out that it might also be that the tick marks with `pgfplotsx()` are *very thin* and (probably) *grey* rather than *transparent*.

Comment: do they look more black, if you disable the grid via `grid = false`?

Comment: @loki: apparently not. In the PDF-zoom, they look quite the same with and without grid and also with arbitrary `gridalpha`.

Comment: off-topic, but since you came up with the grid: meanwhile, I noticed that when I specify any `gridcolor`, the gridlines are above the plot lines (not for scatter points):

`plot(rand(20), gridcolor=:black, grid=true)` produces a plot with gridlines in foreground.

`scatter(rand(20), gridcolor=:black, grid=true)` produces a plot with gridlines in background.

This happens also with other colors, (set `gridalpha=1` for easier visibility).

This is also not the behavior of `gr()` and `pyplot()` so maybe these mechanisms are related.

Comment: Can you try saving your plot as ".tex" file with `text_output_standalone = true` and insert `tick style={color={rgb,1:red,0.0;green,0.0;blue,0.0}}}}` in the options of the `axis`-environment? This might be an oversight from me

Comment: @loki: This renders the tick marks in black! Thank you so far. For an appealing result it would now require to adjust also the width of the mark, e.g. in the width of the axis. Using your method, this can be achieved by adding the option `thick` to your `tick style` handler, i.e. `tick style={color={rgb,1:red,0.0;green,0.0;blue,0.0}, thick}` (omitting the last two brackets from your comment).
Is there any way to add such PGF-Keys as an argument to the `plot()` function?

Comment: So far, my procedure for using `Plots` with `PGFPlotsX` would be as follows: 

call with `plot(..., tex_output_standalone = true)`, then insert the appropriate expression in the `*.tex` file and finally call `lualatex *.tex` for the file.


I automate this via bash: 
`sed -i 's/scaled\ x\ ticks/tick\ style={color={rgb\,1\:red\,0\.0\;green\,0\.0\;blue\,0\.0}\,\ thick}\,\ scaled\ x\ ticks/g' *.tex` and then `for file in *.tex; do lualatex $file; done`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now ticks are not styled by the pgfplotsx-backend. Thanks for the catch.
Best course of action would be to open an issue (or PR) on the github page of `Plots.jl` and I will eventually implement/ review this.

EDIT: That will be fixed in Plots.jl 0.29.8.